# Is there a way to extract the type of the props of a JSX Element?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

My intent is to **extract the props out of a given JSX element**, is it possible?

This was pretty much my failed attempt...
Thanks in advance for any help ;)

```js
function getComponentProps<T extends React.ReactElement>(element: T): ExtractProps<T>;

function Component({ name }: { name: string }) {
  return <h1>{name}</h1>;
}

type ExtractProps<TComponentOrTProps> = TComponentOrTProps extends React.ComponentType<infer TProps>
  ? TProps
  : TComponentOrTProps;

const componentProps = getComponentProps(<Component name="jon" />); //type is JSX.Element
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the most part, you can't do this.

In *theory*, the `React.ReactElement` type is generic with a type parameter `P` that depends on the props. So if you were to have a strongly-typed element then you could work backwards.

```
type ElementProps<T extends React.ReactNode> = T extends React.ReactElement<infer P> ? P : never;
```

In *reality*, you will only get a correct props type if you create your element through `React.createElement` rather than JSX.

Any JSX element `<Component name="John" />` just gets the type `JSX.Element` which obviously has no information about the props so you cannot work backwards from that to a props type.

```
const e1 = React.createElement(
  Component,
  { name: 'John' }
)

type P1 = ElementProps<typeof e1> // type: {name: string}

console.log(getElementProps(e1)); // will log {name: "John"}
```

```
const e2 = <Component name="John" />

type P2 = ElementProps<typeof e2>  // type: any

console.log(getElementProps(e2)); // will log {name: "John"}
```

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/NalrPw)

It is much easier to approach the situation from a different angle.  You will be able to derive the correct props type if your function takes a component like `Component` or `div` rather than a resolved element.  You can use the `ComponentProps` utility type for function and class components and the `JSX.IntrinsicElements` map for built-in ones.

Comment: Honestly, this helps a lot. Thanks for again for the help and the knowledge sharing ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can extract type of the Props for any component using

```
React.ComponentProps<typeof T>
```

You can refer this [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQDMAnmFnACoAKxY6AvHADedOHAB2yEFgBcqGFGBiA5vVHIlMsQFcQAIyxRVcYKgDKMPAGsIANwMEANhADu03RAgOcY%20gF8GdLgQYnJwAIJgYHACABRgPKjSXAkAlNEAfHAAPAAmwDbpABJYDk5wAOrQDjlZAPR5BfQMtbUAmhBacLjIYnBYAB7yePA9TF0kkGJYYjDo8RC8cA7AlmwwABYmAHR0zKzhkdwL-JhUMFsAwhPB0zBHvFl7WBAEB2DpTS0Akq-36EEzZCKdCUAi7FhsCJgP7lYAbbCvATYYaXa5TGYwuHrBGPCEvN4fZq1H5wP4oShwZxYjrwBFLFZrdZsAjAKChFls%20ADSRgLw7J5vTEbGl0pFnVHgG4YhK41j4qGEuhAA) for more options

```
import * as React from 'react';

type TProps = {
   name:string;
   age:number;
   isStackoverflow:boolean;
 }

const App = (props:TProps) => <div>Hello World</div>;

//You can extract any components props like this.
type AppProps = React.ComponentProps<typeof App>;
```

`

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible for `getComponentProps(<Component name="jon" />);`, since written out JSX-Elements always result in the `JSX.Element`-type which doesn't give any additional type information which you could extract. It would be possible if you extract it from the component function itself:

```
export function Component({ name }: { name: string}) {
    return <h1>{name}</h1>;
}

function getComponentProps<T extends (...args: any[]) => JSX.Element>(element: T): Parameters<T>[0] {
    return null as any;
}

const test = getComponentProps(Component); // { name: string;}
```

This solution uses the utility type [parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype), which infers all arguments from a function. We then index the first argument since the prop object is the first argument of a pure jsx function. Class components would need a different solution, though.

Comment: Hum... Yeah, unfortunately what I'm trying isn't achievable then. As I wanted to take a JSX element (probably already with some props) and then return a clone of it which takes the same type of props...

Thanks a lot for the help anyway dude ;)

Comment: @PedroFigueiredo what is the actual use case where you would need to know what props have already been passed?  It's possible that what you want is some manipulation with `React.children` and `cloneElement`.

Comment: It's something like this, where I take a component a clone it with the same props it already takes: https://cutt.ly/XxxZEYe

Comment: So you can take a component and return a component -- that's [just an HOC](https://tsplay.dev/Wyv6dw) and I've typed those a million times :)  You can take an element and return an element [like this](https://tsplay.dev/WvpGRN).  Taking an element and returning a component is something that you can do but it's a bit weird and you're going to have a hard time getting good type support.

Comment: In *theory*, `React.ReactElement` is generic, but you only see those values getting set if you create it through `React.createElement` rather than JSX.

Comment: [How about this?](https://tsplay.dev/W44neW) assigning partial props to intrinsic JSX elements.

Comment: Well, actually thanks a lot @Linda (again :D), I will probably have to build something around this last comment of yours. 

In reality I'm trying to build a tiny lib that takes in some form controls and returns them based on a few defined options. https://github.com/pffigueiredo/react-formgen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230239/discussion-between-pedro-figueiredo-and-linda-paiste).