# Wrapper function for JSX elements, typed via generics

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics

Currently this function works fine

```
function wrapElement(elem: JSX.Element) {
  return ({ ...props }) => React.cloneElement(elem, { ...props })
}
```

I use it like this, because this way I can get intelliSense for tailwind classes

```
const Btn = wrapElement(<button className="[A LOT OF TAILWIND UTILITY CLASSES]" />)
```

But I'm trying to get it to return same type as it receives, so I could get intelliSense for attributes on intrinsic HTML elements.
Right now inferred type is

```
function wrapElement(elem: JSX.Element): ({ ...props }: {
    [x: string]: any;
}) => React.FunctionComponentElement<any>.FunctionComponentElement<any>
```

I tried some stuff and it all failed with all kinds of errors, at this point it feels like this could be to hacky, but maybe I don't understand something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is [basically impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66753903/is-there-a-way-to-extract-the-type-of-the-props-of-a-jsx-element/66754751#66754751) to get the correct props from a `JSX.Element`.  You *can* achieve the design that you want, but you should pass in the element name and the props as separate arguments rather than passing in a `JSX.Element`.

This code can accept an element name like `'button'` or any React component.  It returns a function component with the same props.  I am not dropping any props from the returned component because it seems like you are using this for setting defaults rather than dropping requirements.

```
import React, { ComponentType, ComponentProps } from "react";

const wrapElement = <
  C extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements | ComponentType<any>
>(
  Component: C,
  presetProps: Partial<ComponentProps<C>>
) => (props: ComponentProps<C>) => {
  const merged: ComponentProps<C> = { ...presetProps, ...props };
  return <Component {...merged} />;
};

const Btn = wrapElement("button", {
  className: "[A LOT OF TAILWIND UTILITY CLASSES]"
});

const Dbl = wrapElement(Btn, { onClick: () => alert("clicked") });

const Test = () => {
  return <Dbl>Click</Dbl>;
};
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDeBhCcCAOyWJgBUBPMJbAo08gBSgjAGcBfOAMzZBwARFFQYhAbgCwAKFloSHeAHcoKMAFEANkhBl4AXjgAePHCQAPGGQAmHOAGskVCLzgApAMoANAHQBJcihgYg5gNG1dfXsAHzgGSCZKGiRjFGIqAD5MgAoEkn0ALnjsMFEOJBhWdg5i5hRYYBQtU0JE-WrOU2yASjgDTNk4Ybgcspri-KTOjm6%20gdwhkeWFUPg9KABzJBtJtoKWNi68TP7cXwuypAqqo45sC99xzi5pGWXl0RgAVyhiEym%20nOFw22xsPAA9IN3iMuLJ5Ip4AAhGD-IyqdSRPTkHIAcgARt8YDASLjsDg4GgtCgOBwAHIoPTFIQAbQAgnAADIAeQocG5ADE4BQ2f5OQB1fx0gAicAAqhQxf4KABNeKctmeTwaTwAXSEcC4PTeCLWcGl%20K0Zwxmh02JgORRxHJcBIeC04QcxRy81OzSQsByQipnp2Qj6RpNMlWSmF10Mo19ixhwy%20v3%20OSWHxMFq00Oz2fdnqzH2MENz%20ZGPVkXCAA)

You might want to customize your merge behavior to combine `className` or `style` properties rather than overriding them.

Note: when I tried to merge the props inline like `<Component {...presetProps} {...props} />` I got a weird error "Type `Partial<ComponentProps<C>> & ComponentProps<C>` is not assignable to type `IntrinsicAttributes & LibraryManagedAttributes<C, any>`."  So that is why I am merging the props on a separate line and annotating the type as `ComponentProps<C>` instead of the inferred type `Partial<ComponentProps<C>> & ComponentProps<C>`.

Comment: Oh, wow, this is quite complex! Thank you, I learned a lot