# Helper function to create React component with pre-filled Tailwind classes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

I sometimes extract local Tailwind-styled components like this:

```js
const Container: React.FC = ({ children }) => (
  <div className="bg-white px-5 py-5">
    {children}
  </div>
);
```

To make this easier, I would love to have a helper `styleElement` function that would create the `Container` for me, a bit like this:

```
const Container = styleElement("div", "bg-white px-5 py-5");
```

How would I write the `styleElement` function so that `Container` is correctly typed as a `div` and setting its `className` adds to the defaults? Ie:

```
// Renders as <div className="bg-white px-5 py-5 text-red">…</div>
<Container className="text-red">…</Container>
```

I stress that I want to keep the typing right/tight, so that calling `styleElement("a", …)` would produce a component that accepts the correct props for an `a`.

PS. I have seen [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67201465/wrapper-function-for-jsx-elements-typed-via-generics), but I’m having trouble pivoting the types from the answer there to what I want.

Answer (score 1):

### The function

```
function createElement(tag, classes) {
  return ({ children }) => {
    const Element = tag;

    return <Element className={classes}>{ children }</Element>
  }
}
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33471928/5089567)

### Usage

```
function App() {
  const StyledDiv = createElement('div', 'p-4')
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <StyledDiv>Hello</StyledDiv>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Basic props

```
function createElement(tag: keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements, classes: string) {
  return ({
    children,
    ...props
  }: React.DetailedHTMLProps<
    React.BlockquoteHTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>,
    HTMLElement
  >) => {
    return React.createElement(tag, { ...props, className: classes }, children);
  };
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn’t type the resulting element properly, ie. `createElement("div")` doesn’t lead to a component that accepts `HTMLDivElement`’s props.

Comment: I added a version that will work with TypeScript, but you can't pass tag-specific attributes like the type of button. I'm not sure if this can be done entirely generic. I will look at how styled-components do it.

Comment: Seems like they map [every element](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/main/packages/styled-components/src/utils/domElements.ts) [here](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/main/packages/styled-components/src/constructors/styled.tsx#L14)